# Very strange crash report that I cannot reproduce about segues

Tags: ios, ios6

I have this error in Crashlytics:

```
Fatal Exception NSGenericException
Could not find a navigation controller for segue 'PlanToBusiness'. Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.
```

I only have that segue in one place in the app. And here is the code for it.

```
- (void)performPlanToBusinessSegueOnMainThread
{
    [spinner stopAnimating];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"PlanToBusiness" sender:self];
}
```

Whenever I try to use that area of the app, it works. And the error itself seems to be only occuring for 5% of users. Would anyone know what might be the cause of this? I am using storyboards.

Thanks!

Comment: I assume that the source controller of the segue is embedded in a navigation controller, otherwise this would never work. Is that correct? The only thing I can think of, is that some how the navigation controller is being deallocated or disassociated from the controller you're trying to push from.

Comment: Hello @Genadinik, I'm currently trying to debug the same crash error message. Not able to reliably reproduce. Were you ever able to discover anything?

Comment: I have same problem and can't reproduce it. This crash appears only in iOS 7

Answer (score 1):

You need to embed your view controller inside a UINavigationController[image: Example]

Comment: @janum yeah, but what about not being able to reproduce the problem. Would you know how to try to reproduce this issue?

Comment: If you change the Segue style to something other then Push, It should reproduce.